# authorization_invalid_request error when preparing DocuSign envelope for tab modification

Tags: tabs, docusignapi

I am trying trying to create a draft envelope from a template and then modify some of the tabs in the template.  I'm getting an AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_REQUEST response.

My initial request is to the following URL `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<account id>/envelopes`

and the payload is as follows:

```
{
  "status": "created",
  "emailSubject": "2015-01-27T16:25:43.133-05:00 Docusign Template Request",
  "emailBlurb": "email blurb",
  "templateId": "<template id>",
  "brandId": "<brand id>",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "name": "<name>",
      "email": "<email>",
      "roleName": "<role>",
      "clientUserId": "",
      "emailNotification": {
        "supportedLanguage": "en",
        "emailSubject": "<subject>",
        "emailBody": "special email body"
      }
    }
  ],
  "allowReassign": "true",
  "enableWetSign": "false",
  "messageLock": "false"
}
```

That produces the following response:

```
{
    "envelopeId": "<envelope id>",
    "uri": "/envelopes/<envelope id>",
    "statusDateTime": "2015-01-28T22:09:43.9770000Z",
    "status": "created"
}
```

Then I send a recipient view request to the following URL:
`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/envelopes/<envelope id>/views/recipient` using the envelope id received in the above response.

This results in the following response:

```
{
    "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_REQUEST",
    "message": "The authorization request is malformed."
}
```

Note that if I had set the first request above to a status of "sent" (and thus did *not* create a draft envelope), the second request would have been successful.

However according to DocuSign documentation (p. 163 of the API guide), the modify tabs API call "modifies one or more tabs for a recipient to a draft envelope".  Accordingly to perform a tab modification I need a draft envelope, not a sent one.  But when I create a draft envelope, the views/recipient call fails as above.

I can *add* tabs successfully to a "sent" envelope.  But I would rather *modify* tabs and am having trouble doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You're not hitting a valid DocuSign Endpoint.  Where did you get the `/v2/envelopes/<envelope id>/views/recipient` URL from?  That's not a proper URL hence the error message you are getting.

After you create the envelope if you want to modify a given recipient's tabs then you need to make the following API call:

[Modify Tabs for Recipient](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20Tabs%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm)

Note that this is a `PUT` call not a POST, and URI is:

```
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
```

For example, if you wanted to modify tabs for recipient who is `recipientId = 3` you would make a call similar to (notice the 3 in the URL):

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/12345/envelopes/{envelopeId}/
recipients/3/tabs

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "approveTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }],
    "titleTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }],
    "signHereTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }]
}
```

Comment: I got that uri from the API documentation on page 31.  Its purpose is to retrieve an embedded signing URL.  I did not make my intention clear, sorry.  My _objective_ is to retrieve the URL.  My steps were 1) request envelope from template, 2) request url token, and 3) modify tabs.  My step 2 worked fine as long as step 1 set the status as "sent".  If step 1 sets the status as "created" step 2 fails. I have tried rearranging the steps (request envelope, then modify tabs, then request URL token): the first two steps work, but the third fails with the same error reported above.

Comment: Ran out of space there!  Also please note that the following sequence works: 1) request envelope from template, 2) request url token, and 3) **add** tabs.  That only seems to work if the status is set to "sent" in the first step.  I would much prefer to _modify_ tabs rather than _add_ tabs, so I don't have to worry about tab locations (x and y positions).

Comment: We started getting those errors yesterday as well. Is it possible that docusign changed their API. They have done so in the past and broke our app.

Comment: Note that when I follow the embedded signing walkthrough (http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning) my process works.  I login (of course), post the request for the envelope (with a status of "sent", and request the URL token.  No problem.  The problem only appears when I set the status to "created".  That status is necessary to create a "draft" which in turn is necessary to modify the tabs.  But when the envelope is a draft I can't request a URL token.  I have tried changing the status to "sent" after I modify the tabs, using /v2/accounts/<acct>/envelopes/<envId> and PUT op.

Comment: The status change to "sent" works, but I get the same result "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_REQUEST" when I try to get the URL token

Comment: @Ergin: do you have any resolution for this issue?

Comment: @Ergin This is a problem for us too.  Suddenly stopped working with the same message.

Comment: See William's post... I suspect a bug was caught in the demo (developer) environment and subsequently fixed on DocuSign's side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as an "answer" to my question, but it does appear that the problem has somehow been resolved.  I let it rest for a couple days while I attended to other matters, then yesterday afternoon suddenly it started working, with no changes on my part.  The specific part that wasn't working was attempting a PUT on an envelope in order to modify the tags.  That is not supposed to work unless the envelope is a draft; my envelopes have all been drafts.  Wasn't working a couple days ago, and now it is.  @Pete and @Dorian: you might want to try it again if you haven't already; if you're not doing anything else wrong it might work now.

Comment: Hmm if that's the case I suspect a bug was caught in the demo (developer) environment and subsequently fixed on DocuSign's side.